# Python Code throwing Runtime erroe NZEC?

Tags: python

I was solving a problem on codechef, and successfully tested my python code for the same. For some reason it is saying `Runtime error NZEC` which stands for "Non-zero error code".

my code:

```
N, M = input().split(" ")
N = int(N)
M = int(M)
if (N % 5 == 0 and not N > M):
    print (M - N - 0.50)
else:
    print (M)
```

Link to the problem:
    https://www.codechef.com/problems/HS08TEST

Comment: unrelated, but you probably don't want to do `M = int(M)`

Comment: (also, your result is wrong)

Comment: What version of python is this run on? If it's 2.x, you need `raw_input` instead of `input`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is correct almost just change in one line needed.

```
N, M = input().split(" ")
N = int(N)
# The line below has been changed because M when given at stdin is a 
# float value and during split it is converted to string. But a string
# with decimal can't be converted directly to int, so, it needs to be 
# converted to float
M = float(M)
if (N % 5 == 0 and not N > M):
    print (M - N - 0.50)
else:
    print (M)
```

Comment: Thank you for the valuable suggestion, but even this code isn't working. My primary concern being that the solution to the problem on codechef submitted by all python programmers is showing same error and hence no python submission is submitted. Is there a problem in language that codechef doesn't supports ?